working of mysql window function on top of group by
Consider the table below:
ordersdetails(order_id,product_id,quantity)
(https://i.sstatic.net/gwBbscCI.png)[INPUT TABLE]
The Query that works:
select order_id,max(quantity) as max_qty,
max(avg(quantity)) over() as max_avg_qty_all_orders
from ordersdetails
group by order_id
order by 1;

The Query that throws an error:
select order_id,max(quantity) as max_qty,
avg(quantity) over() as avg_qty_per_order
from ordersdetails
group by order_id
order by 1;

My Question is :

How is this line working on a grouped data

max(avg(quantity)) over()


Why does this below line throw an error then ?

avg(quantity) over() 

Basically I want to understand the working of the window function on a grouped data.
Thank you for your time, Appreciate it !

What do you mean by "doesn't work" and "not work"? Does it error or does it give you an output that you don't expect?

MAX(value) OVER() evaluates to a different value compared to just value. The former computes a single value that is the max of all of them and uses this result for all the rows.

@JNevill I meant it throws an error.

Got it. It's likely throwing an error because you are not aggregating, nor grouping by, the quantity column in the second query. There is an important distinction between window functions and GROUP BY aggregation. They are entirely different steps in SQL processing, where the window functions are always executed AFTER GROUP BY aggregation.

As a rule, SQL query execution order is
1.FROM clause  (included JOIN's)
2.WHERE clause
3.GROUP BY clause
4.HAVING clause
5.SELECT clause
6.ORDER BY clause
This order may differ slightly from one DBMS to another.
However, for MySQL, we can say that SELECT is executed after GROUP BY. Therefore, at this stage there is no longer a quantity value, but there are aggregated values avg(..),sum(...),max(...) and others. Therefore, the window function is executed on aggregated values.
You can write
  max(max(quantity))over(...)

There max(quantity) - is aggregated value.
Your query can be written as
select order_id,max_qty
  ,max(avg_quantity) over() as max_avg_qty_all_orders
from(
  select order_id,
    max(quantity) as max_qty,
    avg(quantity)as avg_qty
  from ordersdetails
  group by order_id
) as intermediate_result
order by 1;

There outer select is executed after GROUP BY.
See more in documentation and letters

So, avg(quantity) over() throws an error because i am using aggregated value which gives here multiple rows ,as a window function and trying to use that result to append it in every row ?

You can write avg(avg(quantity)) over(). This is window operation on values avg(quantity). value quantity do not exists on this stage.
